# How to determine an alphabetic character that is not uppercase or lowercase

Tags: c#, .net

Microsoft uses this rule as one of its complexity rules:

> Any Unicode character that is categorized as an alphabetic character but is not uppercase or lowercase. This includes Unicode characters from Asian languages.

Testing for usual rules, like uppercase can be as simple as `password.Any(char.IsUpper)`.

What test could I use in C# to test for alphabetic Unicode characters that are not uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: Isn't that just !char.IsUpper && !char.IsLower ?

Comment: Are you looking for case when [Char.GetUnicodeCategory(c)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getunicodecategory.aspx) would return `OtherLetter`?

Comment: @RenniePet, not quite, since I don't want punctuation.

Comment: @Alexi, possibly, as long as OtherLetter is not upper or lower.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about the literal translation of the rule:

```
password.Any(c => Char.IsLetter(c) &&
                  !Char.IsUpper(c) &&
                  !Char.IsLower(c))
```

Comment: Just by the way, you shouldn't call your variable `char`, since that's a keyword.

Comment: `c.IsAlphabetical()` might be better than `c.IsLetter()`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly there is no `IsAlphabetical`... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Char_methods.aspx

Comment: @JonnyHenly I'm not familiar with that method either. Where is it defined?

Comment: @metacubed speaking of that link, correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't those methods static. Shouldn't it be `char.IsLetter(c)`?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen of course.. that's what I had written all along.. the edit history _LIES_ :P :D

Comment: @MatthewHaugen that was a joke btw.. thanks for the correction!

Comment: @metacubed isalpha - www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/ from `<cctype>` header

Comment: @JonnyHenly this is C#... your link is C++

Comment: @metacubed, that just makes good sense, doesn't it. I'm hoping to get some samples in Arabic, Korean, Chinese (Simplified and Traditional), and perhaps Cyrillic to test against.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert ascii `a` and `A` to unicode, you'll get `&#0097;` and `&#0065;` so obviously, they are not the same.

---

Update:
Here's an example of what I think you're asking:

```
var c = 'א';
c.Dump();
char.IsUpper(c).Dump("is upper");    // False
char.IsLower(c).Dump("is lower");    // False
char.IsLetterOrDigit(c).Dump("is letter or digit"); // True
char.IsNumber(c).Dump("is Number");  // False
```